# What's the intuition for the fact that $\mathscr{O}(-k)$ and $\mathscr{O}(k)$ are so different?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

maybe this question makes no sense and I just cannot accept the fact that dual the line bundle is different from the respective line bundle itself. Since it looks like that manifolds are more intuitive than algebraic varieties, let's consider smooth complex compact manifolds.

Anyway, picking the most ordinary non-trivial line bundle over a complex manifold , namely the tautological line bundle, it's know that $0 = H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathscr{O}(-k)) \not\cong H^0(\mathbb{P^n}, \mathscr{O}(k)) =$"homogeneous polynomials of degree $k$", because if both have non-trivial global sections then both must be trivial (because the manifold is compact). Another way of seeing this is by computing the cocyles of the respective bundles.

**Is there an intuitive way of seeing why the above one and the dual of the above one are so different (by drawing or seeing where the glueing fails when trying to create a global section)?**

**Where does it fail when I try creating an isomorphism between some a line bundle and it's dual by picking fiberwise isomorphisms (as vector spaces of complex dimension $1$)?**

**If we just consider the smooth structure (without the holomorphic one),what happens to the global sections of both bundles in the above example? Where the fiberwise isomorphism fails to be a vector bundle (of rank $2$) isomorphism?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fiberwise isomorphism fails because there's no canonical way to identify $V$ with $V^*$.

Comment: @Sanchez Actually there is Riesz isomorphism for spaces Hilbert spaces, so it must fail in smoothness or even continuity (don't know how to see this though).

Comment: and that depends on the metric on vector space. The norm on finite dimensional vector space is essentially unique, but when you glue them over different charts, it's not. So if you can put a metric on your bundle - you have the isomorphism. This is the case for real vector bundles (over say, compact manifolds), but not the case for complex vector bundles (over complex manifolds, because you don't have partition of unity)

Comment: @Sanchez Thanks for the comment. I think that you mean holomorphic partition of unit? But  I've heard that even dropping the analyticity condition (maintaining smoothness only) the global sections will differ?

Comment: Hm I see. I'm not sure in the smooth case if they are really different then. (Tend to say they should be the same) But what you wrote down for $H^0$ is definitely holomorphic sections, and so take the complex structure into account.

Comment: So I guess the point here would be, you cannot glue Hermitian metric holomorphically, but you can do so smoothly. This means that the isomorphism doesn't work for the case of holomorphic sections, but should work for the case of smooth sections

Comment: @Sanchez A professor of mine said that the isomorphism does not hold for the smooth case.

Comment: A vector bundle in the smooth category has a Riemannian metric, and that allows you to write down explicitly an isomorphism to the dual bundle.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez   Thanks for the comment.So these two bundles will not be dual to each other in the real sense, right?

Comment: @user40276 Are you familiar with the understanding of line bundles in terms of divisors? If you are, then if you think about $\mathcal{O}(n)$ as $nH_0$ (where $H_0$ is the hyperplane $V(x_0)$) and $\mathcal{O}(-n)$ as $-nH_0$, then the global sections of $\mathcal{O}(n)$ are rational functions which must only have one possible pole, at $H_0$, and there the pole can be no worse than of order $n$. Global sections of $\mathcal{O}(-n)$ says that the global sections must have NO poles, and a zero of order at least $n$ at $H_0$. But, you can't have no poles if you have zeros, if you're non-zero.

Comment: @user40276 So, morally if you think about bundles as being specifications of functions with "pole/zero" data, then it's clear why $\mathcal{O}(-k)$ and $\mathcal{O}(k)$ are different. The fact that the specification is $\text{div}(f)\geqslant -D$, for elements of $f\in K(X)$, says that if $-D$ is effective, then $D$ itself is specifying untenable global data. But, if $D$ is effective, there is no a priori unrealistic conditions being imposed on global sections. This also gives you an intuition about what is the  difference between complex and real bundles. On real manifolds there aren't

Comment: as stringent of conditions on what global functions must satisfy. So, we should expect that bundles should behave different there.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thanks, your comment was very helpful.

Comment: @user40276 You're welcome :)

Answer (score 9):

Since I find some comments to the question a bit ambiguous, let me emphasize:

**For $k\gt0$ the line bundles $\mathcal O(k)$ and $\mathcal O(-k)$ are not isomorphic in the $C^0$-category   and thus *a fortiori* not isomorphic in the $C^\infty$-category.**

In other words, the non-isomorphism you are asking about has nothing to do with algebraic geometry and can already been read on the underlying topological manifold and underlying topological bundles.
The most convincing proof is through the use of the first Chern classes:$$ c_1(\mathcal O(k))=k\neq   c_1(\mathcal O(-k))=-k\in H^2(\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C),\mathbb C)=\mathbb C$$  Beware that if a **real** line bundle has a riemannian metric, then it is isomorphic to its dual but if a **complex** line bundle $E$ has a hermitian metric (which is the case for $E=\mathcal O(k)$) you can only say that its dual $E^\ast$ is isomorphic to its conjugate bundle $\overline E$, but not to $E$ itself.

**Bibliography**
By far the best resource for these results is Milnor-Stasheff's justly celebrated [*Characteristic Classes*](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Characteristic_Classes.html?id=5zQ9AFk1i4EC&redir_esc=y), especially §§ 13, 14.

Comment: Georges, while your answer is certainly 100% correct content wise, I disagree that the original question has absolute nothing to do with algebraic geometry. While it is certainly true that the Chern classes tell the bundles apart, it is hard to understand intuitively what the difference in Chern classes (beyond "they have different orientation twisting") tells us. It's a kind of technical fact which is, as hard, if not harder, to reconcile than the global sections argument. I do think that understanding why the bundles are specifying different pole data, and so shouldn't be the same, is more

Comment: intuitive, despite using ideas (algebraic/complex geometry) which are, technically, unneeded. Regardless, this is a good answer, clarifying some of the ambiguous comments (including mine!) about the differences between the real and complex cases. +1!

Comment: Dear @Alex,  yes, you are right: the statement that this non-isomorphism has nothing to do with algebraic geometry is a bit of an overstatement. I just wanted to emphasize that the non-isomorphism already  exists at the topological level and is not due to some strange  definition/convention invented by weird algebraic geometers :-) Anyway, thanks for your attention and your interesting comment.

Comment: They are a wily bunch. Thank heavens we have the non-algebraic geometers like you to safeguard us from their devissage and their pro-etale sites. :)

Comment: Dear @Alex: yes, be very afraid of their wily schemes...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but some things still not clear for me. Are real vector bundles always isomorphic to their duals (respectively)? If yes, then $\mathscr{O}(k)$ is not dual to $\mathscr{O}(-k)$ as real vector bundles of rank 2, right? Furthermore, what´s the problem with the fiberwise isomorphism (why they are not globally isomorphisms)? Does continuity fail (or smoothness)?