# Is $\mathcal{O}(-1)\cong\mathcal{O}(1)$?

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

*Disclaimer: I use some algebraic geometry notation below, out of convenience, but I know nothing about algebraic geometry.*

As far as I can tell, the oriented 2-dimensional **real** vector bundles over $S^2\cong\mathbb{CP}^1$ are given by $\mathcal{O}(k)$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. All of these are distinct: $\mathcal{O}(m)$ is not isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}(n)$ for $m\neq n$.

But what if we remove the orientation? Could it be true some of these become isomorphic as real vector bundles, like $\mathcal{O}(k)\cong\mathcal{O}(-k)$?

I tried to do this for the simplest example: $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and $\mathcal{O}(-1)$. Looking around on the internet, I found the following total spaces for these bundles:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{O}(-1) &= \{([\ell],v)\in\mathbb{CP}^1\times\mathbb{C}^2\mid v\in\ell\}\\
\mathcal{O}(1) &= \mathbb{CP}^2\setminus[0:0:1]
\end{align*}

But I can't convince myself these spaces are homeomorphic, let alone bundle-isomorphic. And this is where I get confused: some answers on this site (like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/744776/320311)) seem to suggest these two total spaces are not homeomorphic. But other answers (like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76559/320311)) seem to suggest they only differ by the per-fiber orientation.

So: is $\mathcal{O}(-1)\cong\mathcal{O}(1)$ as real non-oriented vector bundles over $S^2$? If not, why not? If so, is there an explicit bundle isomorphism?

Comment: Suggestion (don't know if this works, you can check): every real vector bundle is isomorphic to its dual. Now, $\mathcal{O}(k)$ is by definition dual to $\mathcal{O}(-k)$ as a complex (or holomorphic) line bundle, so maybe you can use this when forgetting about the holomorphic and complex structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can give an explicit bundle isomorphism between $\mathcal{O}(1)$ and $\mathcal{O}(-1)$. I'll write $S$ and $T$ for the total spaces you listed in the question, so that $S$ is $\mathbb{CP}^2$ minus $[0:0:1]$ and $T$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{CP}^1\times\mathbb{C}^2$.

Since we want a bundle isomorphism, we need to send the point $[x:y:z]\in S$ to a point that looks like $\big([x:y]; v\big)\in T$. A naive choice of $v$ would be to scale the point $(x,y)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ by $z$:
\begin{equation*}
v = (xz, yz)
\end{equation*}

But this isn't well-defined. A slightly better approach is to first normalize $(x,y)$:
\begin{equation*}
v = \frac{(xz, yz)}{|x|^2+|y|^2}
\end{equation*}

This is better, but still not well-defined, since $[\lambda x:\lambda y:\lambda z]$ goes to different $v$ for different values of $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}^\ast$. That's where the complex conjugation comes in:
\begin{equation*}
v = \frac{(x\overline{z}, y\overline{z})}{|x|^2+|y|^2}
\end{equation*}

This is now well-defined and gives a continuous map from $S$ to $T$, that covers the identity map on $\mathbb{CP}^1$:
\begin{equation*}
F([x:y:z]) = \bigg([x:y];\frac{\overline{z}(x, y)}{|x|^2+|y|^2}\bigg)
\end{equation*}

Let $U_x=\{[x:y]\in\mathbb{CP}^1\mid x\neq0\}$, and similarly for $U_y$. Then the trivialization for $S$ is given by
\begin{align*}
U_x\times\mathbb{C} &\rightarrow \pi_S^{-1}(U_x)& U_y\times\mathbb{C} &\rightarrow \pi_S^{-1}(U_y)\\
\big([x:y],z\big)&\mapsto [x:y:xz] & \big([x:y],z\big)&\mapsto [x:y:yz]
\end{align*}
I'll abuse notation and write both of these as $\rho_S$. We can also write the trivialization for $\rho_T$:
\begin{align*}
U_x\times\mathbb{C} &\rightarrow \pi_T^{-1}(U_x)& U_y\times\mathbb{C} &\rightarrow \pi_T^{-1}(U_y)\\
\big([x:y],z\big)&\mapsto \big([x:y];(z,\tfrac{y}{x}z\big) & \big([x:y],z\big)&\mapsto \big([x:y];(\tfrac{x}{y}z,z\big)
\end{align*}

These trivializations can then show what $F$ does to fibers, and show it really is a bundle isomorphism. For example, if $[x:y]\in U_x$ then
\begin{equation*}
\rho_T^{-1}F\rho_S(z) = \overline{z}\frac{|x|^2}{|x|^2+|y|^2}
\end{equation*}
which is certainly an invertible $\mathbb{R}$-linear map.

**EDIT**: It's possible to also give a definition for $F^{-1}$
\begin{equation*}
F^{-1}([x,y]; v) = \begin{cases}
[x:y:0] & v=0\\
[v:|v|^2] & v\neq0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Thanks this is perfect!

Answer (score 6):

One may prove that any complex vector bundle, viewed as a real, unoriented vector bundle is isomorphic to its complex dual as follows:

Let $\xi$ be a complex vector bundle over a base $B$ (assume this space to be paracompact). By a partition of unity argument, there exists a hermitian metric $h: \bar\xi\otimes \xi\to \underline{\mathbb{C}}$, where $\bar{\xi}$ denotes the conjugate bundle to $\xi$ and $\underline{\mathbb{C}}$ is the trivial complex line over $B$. One may view this as a map $\bar{\xi}\to \mathrm{Hom}(\xi, \mathbb{C}); v\mapsto(u\mapsto h(v,u))$ and the fact that this is a hermitian metric means that this is an isomorphism of complex vector bundles. Note that the underlying unoriented vector bundles $\xi$ and $\bar{\xi}$ are the same. These only differ in the complex structure given to them. This means that the map $(v\mapsto v)$ is an isomorphism of real vector bundles (this is real linear but complex antilinear). The composition $\xi\to \bar{\xi}\to \mathrm{Hom}(\xi, \mathbb{C})$ then gives a real vector bundle isomorphism between $\xi$ and $\xi^*=\mathrm{Hom}(\xi,\mathbb{C})$.

Just as a sanity check, we can see that this makes sense on the level of Stiefel-Whitney classes. The Stiefel-Whitney classes of a complex vector bundle are the mod 2 reduction of the Chern classes and the Chern classes of the conjugate bundle of $\xi$ are given by $c_i(\bar{\xi})=(-1)^{i}c_i(\xi)$ so the Stiefel-Whitney classes of $\xi$ match those of $\bar{\xi}$.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! So they are indeed isomorphic. Do you know if there's an explicit bundle isomorphism? I guess one way would be to build this map $h$ directly, which maybe isn't *too* bad, because $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ can be trivialized in only 2 charts. But before I go down that road: does that sound reasonable or is there a better way to try and find such an isomorphism?

Comment: Because the fibers of $\mathcal{O}(-1)$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, putting a hermitian metric on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ yields one on $\mathcal{O}(-1)$. It is a small exercise to find an expression for the metric when one puts the standard metric on $\mathbb{C}^2$ with respect to the stereographic projection charts on $\mathbb{C}P^1$.